# Reading Connection string from application Config file

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a connection string from the application configuration file.

But keep receiving an error:

> The name ConfigurationManager does in exit in current context.

After googling the error, I added ConfigurationManager to my project. But I still get the same error.

My code:

```
string sqlConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ToString();`
```

My application config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AppConnectionString" connectionString="SERVER=1894; Database=db; UID=loss;  PWD=where;encrypt=no;enlist=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Add "using System.Configuration;"

Comment: And make sure you've added a reference to the System.Configuration assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have referenced `System.configuration`.

Then make sure you either import the correct namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

or use the full typename

```
string sqlConStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ConnectionString`

```
var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```